# Does this probability statement have a closed form? (Extreme value distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, closed-form

**Problem Statement:**
Does this probability statement have a closed form solution?

> $\mathbb{P}\left(\min\left\{ w,p\right\} >c\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\min\left\{ \left(\frac{a+\epsilon_{1}-\epsilon_{0}}{b}\right),p\right\} >c\right)$,

where:

- $a,b,c$ and $p$ are known (constants).
- $\epsilon_{1}$
  and $\epsilon_{0}$
  are both extreme value random variables (assumed to be independent of each other).

**My Attempt: ($\wedge$ denotes “and” below)**

> $\mathbb{P}\left(\min\left\{ w,p\right\} >c\right)=\mathbb{P}(w<p\wedge w>c)+\mathbb{P}(w>p\wedge p>c)$

by Baye's formula I can decompose the joint probability into:

> $=\mathbb{P}(w<p)\cdot\mathbb{P}(w>c\mid w<p)+\mathbb{P}(w>p)\cdot \mathbb{P}(p>c\mid w>p)$

where (I think) that

> $\mathbb{P}(w<p)=\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_{1}-\epsilon_{0}<p\cdot b-a)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{exp(-(p \cdot b-a))},$ 
>   $\mathbb{P}(w>p)=\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_{0}-\epsilon_{1}<a-b \cdot p)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{exp(-(a-b \cdot p))}$

(where the final step is due to the Logit formula).

However, I am not sure that the conditional probabilities $\mathbb{P}(w>c\mid w<p)$
  and $\mathbb{P}(p>c\mid w>p)$ have a closed form? Here is my attempt for the first one:

> $\mathbb{P}(w>c\mid w<p)=\mathbb{P}(\epsilon_{0}-\epsilon_{1}<a-b\cdot c\mid\epsilon_{0}-\epsilon_{1}>a-b \cdot p)$

*Is this a truncated Logit probaility? What is its closed form (if it has one)?*

I am trying to learn this, so please point out any flaws/mistakes in my reasoning. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by closed form? what is $w$? Where does this problem come from? Is this supposed to be Logit distributed? Where are you getting these probability distributions from? What is your question and how did you come to have this question?